# Table 'project_dev.users' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I just created a new table using a Rails migration, then I created a model where I added in its relationships.

I have restarted my console, and the MySQL console shows the table in the project_dev database.

When I try to create a new record in my Ruby console, I get:

`Mysql::Error: Table 'project_dev.trace_users' doesn't exist
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:287:in 'query'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:287:in 'execute'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:438:in 'columns'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/base.rb:679:in 'columns'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/persistence.rb:285:in 'attributes_from_column_definition'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/locking/optimistic.rb:62:in 'attributes_from_column_definition'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/act
ive_record/base.rb:1396:in 'initialize'
        from (irb):2:in 'new'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/c
ommands/console.rb:44:in 'start'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/c
ommands/console.rb:8:in 'start'
        from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:23:in '<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in 'require'
        from script/rails:6:in '<main>'`

Comment: Well, does `trace_users` exist?

Comment: @Pekka... see my answer below o=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was a little more incompetent yesterday than I'd otherwise like to admit - the migration tables had been created in singular form instead of plural - this led to the table trace_user instead of trace_users.

@Ben - I called the table that because I have a few trace tables in the system recording different kinds of events, and I preferred to have all the trace tables together - IMHO this helps to make the tables easier to understand when trying to comprehend the system as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You had a User model and then added a Trace model, right? You did everything right, except that since you added has_many users in Trace, you now have to create the association table (through another migration). Consider getting the association direction correct (user has_many traces?) so that the table is user_traces, which to me sounds better.